# Hide the Ajax thank you message, after 3 seconds and display Main Form

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am create a Contact Us Form with jQuery Validation and jQuery Ajax submission.

After the message is displayed via Ajax for 3 seconds the mesage should be visible to user, after that the form should re-appear.

Here is my HTML codespec:

```
<form id="contactForm" name="contactForm" method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="txtName" name="name" class="required" style="color:#999;" /><br />
  <input type="text" name="email" id="txtEmail" placeholder="E-mail" class="required" style="color:#999;" /><br />
  <textarea id="textareaMessage" name="message" rows="5" cols="10" class="required" style="color:#999;"></textarea><br /><br />
  <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Here is my jQuery Validation and jQuery Ajax submission codespec:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contactForm").validate({
      rules: { 
        name: "required",// simple rule, converted to {required:true} 
        email: {// compound rule 
          required: true, 
          email: true 
        }, 
        message: { 
          required: true 
        } 
      },
      submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "send.php",
          data: $(form).serialize(),
          timeout: 3000,
          success: function() {
            $('#divContactFrm').html("<div id='divSuccessMsg'></div>");
            $('#divSuccessMsg').html("Thank you! Your message has been sent to us. We will be getting back to you within 24 hours.")
            .hide()
            .fadeIn(1500, function() { $('#divSuccessMsg'); });
          },
          error: function() {
            $('#divContactFrm').html("<div id='divErrorMsg'></div>");
            $('#divErrorMsg').html("Something is going wrong...")
            .hide()
            .fadeIn(1500, function() { $('#divErrorMsg'); });
          }
        });
        return false;
      }     
    });
  });
</script>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell what poblem you are facing with this implementation? a live demo at jsfiddle.net can be helpful too

Comment: I am not facing any problem with Ajax or jQuery Validation. I want to know how to make the Ajax message disappear after 3 seconds and make the form reappear... Here is a link to a live demo... http://www.ivanbayross.com/jquerytest/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  submitHandler: function(form) {


        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "send.php",
          data: $(form).serialize(),
          timeout: 3000,
          success: function() {
            $("#contactForm").hide();
            $('#divContactFrm').html("<div id='divSuccessMsg'></div>");
            $('#divSuccessMsg').html("Thank you! Your message has been sent to us. We will be getting back to you within 24 hours.")
            .hide()
            .fadeIn(1500, function() { $('#divSuccessMsg'); });
           setTimeout(resetAll,3000);
          },
          error: function() {
            $('#divContactFrm').html("<div id='divErrorMsg'></div>");
            $('#divErrorMsg').html("Something is going wrong...")
            .hide()
            .fadeIn(1500, function() { $('#divErrorMsg'); });
          }
        });
        return false;
      }
```

And

```
function resetAll(){
 $("#contactForm").show();
$('#divSuccessMsg').remove(); // Removing it as with next form submit you will be adding the div again in your code. 

}
```

Points to note `$("#contactForm").hide();` as soon as Ajax successful and `setTimeout(resetAll,3000);` a the `success Handler's End`...

Let me knwo if this solves your issue.

Comment: Hi Rahul Maindargi, Thank You very much for your help. Really appreciated the quick response... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this on success function:

```
jQuery(form_id).fadeOut('slow', function() {
        jQuery(thanks_id).fadeIn('slow');
        jQuery(form_id)[0].reset();
});

setTimeout(function (){

        jQuery(thanks_id).fadeOut('slow', function() {
            jQuery(form_id).fadeIn('slow', function(){});
            jQuery(form_id)[0].reset();
        });

}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide the form before submitting then use the following code in ajax callback function

```
 $('#divId').text(" successfully").show().delay(2000).fadeOut(400);
 $('#contactForm').show();
```

Comment: Hi PSR, sorry not so familiar with jQuery. Hence please can you tell me in which section do I hide the form. I did add the code which you can me in the success function but it did not work.. What am I doing wrong..

Comment: when you click on submit button then hide

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeOut`, to hide the div after 3 seconds.

```
 success: function() {
   $('#divSuccessMsg').html("Thank you!.")
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('#divSuccessMsg').fadeOut();
    },3000);
 }
```